# generate NSString off of UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextfield

i need to generate a NSString named after a UITextField..Then i also need to be able to use this string. anyone have any kind of idea to do something like this?

Thanks,
Jacob

Edit:

The user will type in his/her name..this name will then be generated into a NSString--It will be the strings name. Like how you would say

```
NSString *NAME;
```

i need the string to be named whatever there name is.

Comment: Could you provide more context? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: You mean you want to generate variable name based on text field contents? like if I typed hello, then you want to get "NSString *hello" ? Why do you want that? may be there're better ways...

Comment: well this string is being saved to a file, as i recall the string name also gets saved when you save it to a plst file?

Comment: plist format it depends on what structure you save, but variable name is not saved to file

Comment: Ahh it doesnt. I see. Okay well i think i thought up a solution then. hmm. Thanks for the help though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
NSString *myString = [[myUITextField stringValue] retain];
```

Comment: well i dont need the content of the string to be named after the textfield, i need the actual string name

Comment: Oh, I see, you want the name of the string. The name is in the NSTextField, and the string contained in there doesn't have a(n accessible) name, AFAIK. Or do you want to generate a string that has the name "hello", like @Vladimir says? That is impossible, since the name must be known at compile time.

Comment: FWIW, under what key the string is stored in a plist is up to you. You could use a simplified version of the text as key.